# Is querying a MySQL database dozens of times in order to allow effective caching better than a few large queries with less caching?

Tags: php, mysql, caching

In my application, I try to grab all the data I need in as few queries as possible. This usually leads to large queries with many joins. This places limits on what you can cache using software like Memcache or Redis (as far as I know). With large queries, you don't know what parts might already be cached. It seems like you have to query everything in smaller parts so that these small parts can be cached individually. The idea would be that you only have to do dozens of small queries in order to populate caches and that most of the time you would hit the caches rather than query. Is this how high traffic PHP/MySQL websites handle this? Is there a good way to cache effectively even if you have large queries with many joins?

Example:

```
SELECT user.name, user.birthday 
FROM follower
    INNER JOIN user ON (user.id = follower.user)
WHERE follower.following = '1'
```

The results of this query include the names and birthdays of any users following user 1. The results of this query could be cached, but that would only be useful when getting followers of user 1.

The alternative:

```
SELECT follower.user
FROM follower
WHERE follower.following = '1'
```

For each result with ? populated by follower.user from the previous query:

```
SELECT name, birthday FROM user where user.id = ?
```

In this case, we can check to see if user ?'s name and birthday are cached before querying for them from MySQL. If they aren't cached, or some are cached and some not, then grab the missing ones and cache them. You could also cache the list of follower IDs and then none of the queries need to be run the next time. The difference is that the name and birthdays of the users will be useful to any other user that ends up need information about these followers in any other context.

Am I missing something on caching with larger queries? Or is the second way the right way?

Comment: "This usually leads to large queries with many joins", mean also a lot of result rows?

Comment: I believe that with PHP has some sort of prepare_query function which does some work on a query and then all you have to do is set the parameters to run it. These prepared statements can make the execution of lots of queries faster as the database engine won't have to do all preparations before them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct answer is: It depends.

Caching is a way of optimizing a recognized use pattern by shortcutting producing repeatedly expensive data with re-using the data from a previous run.

So the first question you should answer is: It there an observed repeated use pattern that has a noticable "expensive" step of producing data? If not: Don't use caching that you still do not need, wait until you can observe something.

The second question you should be able to answer is: Can you measure how long it takes with and without cache, and is the difference noticable?

And the third important question to answer is: How can you clean the cache from outdated information if the original data gets changed, and you want that new data to be displayed instantly?

So in your case you are asking if using a cache for plenty of small, but seemingly more universal queries that then get combined is more beneficial than caching one big query. There is no theoretical answer, because it depends on how much faster a cache hit for a big result is compared to multiple cache hits for the combined result. Making multiple requests to the cache may very well be SLOWER than fetching the data from the original source, and combining the data into the needed complex result might also be slower than fetching ONE complex result directly from the cache.

Also, if using multiple cache entries for a combined result, you'll now have to deal with plenty of cases where only parts of the information are outdated, while others are not. So the result just gets more unreliable - you cannot really be sure if every part of the result is up to date, or how old it is.

Answer (score 0):

@Sven you make the point! I add few more *raw* suggestions.

@Barakat big queries usually are not a big deal for MySql, well designed db, indexes and tuning the engine parameters usually give high performances.

Do many little queries induces a lot of overhead (cached or not), I usually avoid that.

If your big query gives big results (hundred/thousands of row), may be you can avoid it paging the results or limit the answers to best scores.

A very simple and effecting tool to tune your mysql server is [MysqlTuner.pl](https://github.com/major/MySQLTuner-perl), because you can use the MySql **internal** cache without worry about coherence!